# How to customize entity Field Type in Symfony 2.1 so it uses specific repository method?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, repository, entity

I am new to symfony (2.1) and I have simple problem, I want to change the way that "entity Field Type" generates choice list in select tag in form.

In my categoryType.php, in buildForm method I have something like this:

```
$builder
   ->add('parent', 'entity', array(
   'class' => 'TestAdvBundle:Category',
   'property' => 'name',
   'label'  => 'label.parent',
))
;
```

This works fine, all Category entities which are persisted in db are present in select tag in generated form. But what I want to do is to slightly change this generated choice list. Actually, I want one "fake" choice in list which represents "root category" and I do not want object that I edit to be listed here (this field is a parent id, and it points to same object type as the edited object is, etc. this field is parent category of category that I edit, so practically I don't want to be able to select self as a parent category).

I guess that this "entity Field Type" uses `findAll()` repository method to fetch its results. So I made specific `findAllForList()` method where I return wanted array. But I can not find a way to tell "entity Field Type" to use my repository method instead of `findAll()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Querybuilder option and the empty_field Method provided with the entity field type.
http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder

The querybuilder is explained in the linked URL under "Using a Custom Query for the Entities"